# How can I find folder owner without read access using AD?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am very new to AD and to powershell and I can't quite figure this out.

Lets suppose I have this folder `"\\server\Departament\ExampleFolder"` and I don't have any permissions to read, I can't even see who the owner is. `Get-Acl` returns me an error `UnauthorizedAccessException` because well, I don't have any permission to do so.

I need to create a script that finds the owner of this folder and sends a email asking for access permissions.

My question is this: There is anyway I can find the folder owner using AD without having any permission to the folder?

The owner it's in the same ad domain as me (at least it should be)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

If you look at the NTFS [File Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732880(v%3Dws.10)) table, you will need at least the **Special Permission:** ***Read Permissions*** privilege in order to read the permissions including folder ownership. If you don't have the general ***Read*** permissions or **Special Permission:** ***Read Permissions*** privilege, then you can't see folder ownership at all.

There is no way around it or tricks... because security is... well... security and that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

you must first take ownership to see who has access, although overwriting means you will never who used to have ownership. if you are the network admin administering access to these files then you can click on change, navigate to the location of that server admin, and apply, then push down to all child objects (NOTE do not push the NTFS permissions JUST the owner)
i do believe that MS should allow you to view owner of a folder even without read, but not the full permissions list or of course, no files. but allowing you to view owner means you could then ask that owner for access without any security breaches to the files themselves